# How to use @use in Angular Component ts file

Tags: angular, material-design

I need to include some Material design components in my angular app.

I am trying to use

import {MDCDataTable} from '@material/data-table';

@use "@material/data-table/data-table";

@Use is not accepted.

Comment: You could try the `MatTableModule` from `@angular/material` package: https://material.angular.io/components/table/api

Comment: @use is part of the sass syntax - is it usable in the TS as welll for some reasons?

Comment: I am trying to Integrate Material web component in Angular directly. ie (mdc textfield , mdc button , MDC data table). Is it possible